# regarding the understanding of a code segment of using zip function in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I once saw the following code segment, and I am not very clear how does this code segment work, especially, the usage of `feature_bool in zip(["HOG", "color histogram", "spatial"], ['True', 'True', 'False'])`

```
features = [feature_name for feature_name, feature_bool
        in zip(["HOG", "color histogram", "spatial"],
               ['True', 'True', 'False'])
        if feature_bool == True]
```

Comment: [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) joins two lists together. Tying each index to each other. The code ties the two together, and then only returns the ones where `True` matches. This would be `hog` and `color histogram`.

Comment: `print(list(zip("abc", "ABC")))`

Comment: It doesn't work. `True` will never equal `'True'` or `'False'`, so you end up with an empty list

Comment: The output of the above code will be an empty list. Reason: The values in the second list are strings and not boolean values. If you want to get a result, you need to change `if feature_bool == 'True'` or you need to change the list from `['True', 'True', 'False']` to `[True, True, False]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the above code will be an empty list.

Reason: The values in the second list are strings and not boolean values.

If you want to get a result, you need to change

```
if feature_bool == 'True'
```

or you need to change the list from

```
['True', 'True', 'False']
```

to

```
[True, True, False]
```

**Detailed explanation below:**

Let's break this solution down into smaller bits:

First let's see what happens when we do a zip.

## understanding zip

```
a = ['HOG', 'color histogram', 'spatial']
b = ['True', 'True', 'False']
x = zip(a, b)
print(list(x))
```

The output of this will be:

```
[('HOG', 'True'), ('color histogram', 'True'), ('spatial', 'False')]
```

## for loop with two lists

Next, we are going to have the value in x iterated through a for loop.

```
for feature_name, feature_bool in [('HOG', 'True'), ('color histogram', 'True'), ('spatial', 'False')]:
    print (feature_name, feature_bool)
```

The output of this will be:

```
HOG True
color histogram True
spatial False
```

Note here that the values `True` and `False` are strings and not boolean values. i.e., the values are `'True'` and `'False'`

## If statement check for `feature_bool`

Then we are checking if feature_bool is a boolean value of True. In this case, the value is a string of 'True'

It does not match. We are checking as follows:

```
if 'True' == True #string of True is same as boolean of True
```

## finally, list comprehension to create the final list

Finally, the list comprehension is looking to push a value only when the if statement is True. In our case, none of the if statement resulted in  True. Therefore the final list is empty

## How to fix the code:

Two options to fix code:

**Option 1:**

change the if statement as follows:

```
if feature_bool == 'True'
```

**Option 2:**

Change the values in the second list

from

```
['True', 'True', 'False']
```

to

```
[True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.